# ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE MIPS AVERAGE 4 NUMBERS

Tags: assembly, mips

Please help me figure out what is the error in the below code. The code adds 4 numbers and displays the Average output. [MIPS ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE]. I have almost completed the code but I can not figure out what seems to be the problem. I have recently started studying MIPS and I am not every good with the syntax. Please help me where I am wrong. Apologies for my bad English, English is not my first language.

```
    .data
first_prmpt: .asciiz " Enter first integer: \n"
   second_prmpt: .asciiz " Enter second integer: \n"
   third_prmpt: .asciiz " Enter third integer: \n"
   fourth_prmpt: .asciiz " Enter fourth integer: \n"
   avg: .asciiz " The average is: "

.text
main:
   
   li $v0, 4        # syscall to print string
   la $a0, first_prmpt
   syscall

   li $v0, 5        # syscall to read an integer
   syscall
   move $t0, $v0        # move number to read into $t0

   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, second_prmpt
   syscall

   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t1, $v0

   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, third_prmpt
   syscall

   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t2, $v0

   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, fourth_prmpt
   syscall

   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t3, $v0

   add $a0, $t0, $t1, $t2, $t3, $t4
   li $v0, 1
   syscall
   
   li $t5,4

   div $t4, $t4, $t5


   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, avg
   syscall

   move $a0, $t4     
   li $v0, 1      
   syscall


exit:
   li $v0, 10
   syscall
```

The syntax error lies in this part of code

```
   add $a0, $t0, $t1, $t2, $t3, $t4
   li $v0, 1
   syscall
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can't `add` more than 2 numbers at a time. Try breaking it into multiple operations and use temporary registers.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in adding was that instead of adding all the numbers together I added each number individually. For the first step we added first two numbers and saved them in t4. However remaining were just added to t4 one by one.
The code with comments:

```
.data

   first_prmpt: .asciiz " Enter first integer: \n"
   second_prmpt: .asciiz " Enter second integer: \n"
   third_prmpt: .asciiz " Enter third integer: \n"
   fourth_prmpt: .asciiz " Enter fourth integer: \n"
   avg: .asciiz " The average is: "

.text
main:

   # Prompt For First Number
   li $v0, 4        # syscall to print string
   la $a0, first_prmpt
   syscall

   # Read First Number.
   li $v0, 5        # syscall to read an integer
   syscall
   move $t0, $v0        # move number to read into $t0

   # Prompt For Second Number
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, second_prmpt
   syscall

   # Read Second Number
   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t1, $v0

   # Prompt For Third Number
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, third_prmpt
   syscall

   # Read Third
   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t2, $v0

   # Prompt For Fourth Number
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, fourth_prmpt
   syscall

   # Read Fourth Number
   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t3, $v0

   # add all numbers
   add $t4, $t0, $t1
   add $t4, $t4, $t2
   add $t4, $t4, $t3

   li $t5,4

   # Average
   div $t4, $t4, $t5

  

   # Print Average

   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, avg
   syscall

   move $a0, $t4     
   li $v0, 1      
   syscall


exit:
   li $v0, 10
   syscall
```